# Linq Concat to Lazy-Load it's contents

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq

```
var seq = 
         GetCollectionA()
          .Concat(GetCollectionB())
          .Concat(GetCollectionC())
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

If `GetCollectionA()` returned some objects, the other two methods wrapped in `Concat` would still run, and for nothing. And each one of those methods return an actual array, not a true Linq-friendly Enumerable. My goal is to have parameters to `Concat` evaluated when they are actually needed. Wouldn't it be nice if Concat was done to allow lazy-loading lambda expressions like so?

```
var seq = 
         GetCollectionA()
          .Concat(() => GetCollectionB())
          .Concat(() => GetCollectionC())
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am thinking about the following workaround, will this work and not call the subsequent collection methods if the element is found in first collection?

```
var seq = 
         GetCollectionA()
          .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 1).SelectMany(_ => GetCollectionB()))
          .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 1).SelectMany(_ => GetCollectionC()))
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is `Concat` going to actually iterate the sequence anyway instead of putting it on iteration pipeline?

Is there a better way?

Comment: `If GetCollectionA() returned some objects, the other two methods wrapped in Concat would still run, and for nothing` this is a strange way to ask a question, i mean, why is it for nothing?, looks normal to me. Are you perhaps asking, if you can conditionally load elements based on the previous call? if so create your own extension method, or use an if statment

Comment: @TheGeneral Look at the end of my Linq statement, I only need one element, it shouldn't iterate through the whole collection. And if my Get methods are heavy on CPU, why do I want to run all 3 if only the first one gets me what I am looking for?

Comment: @TheGeneral Why do I need to write a procedural if-else code which is more error prone if I could simply do it using a simple declarative Linq query? I already listed a working sample.

Comment: (1/2) Your question is quite confusing... Also after looking at it and answers I get what you trying to avoid... but you are blaming `.Concat` for something that is not related to it at all - parameters are evaluated before the call so `.Concat` has no chance to do anything about it... It will not *enumerate* sequence (which is expected behavior for LINQ chains). Your sample shows that `GetCollectionX()` is by itself not exactly LINQ friendly - they should do roughly nothing when result not iterated while yours "if my Get methods are heavy on CPU"...

Comment: (2/2) some other reasoning or sample may better explain what you want to achieve... Or just simply stating that you don't want parameters to be evaluated before needed may clarify the post.

Comment: `it shouldn't iterate through the whole collection` Technically, it isn't _iterating_ through the whole collection. It only iterates over `GetCollectionA`. I think what you are **really** asking for is 'don't execute `GetCollectionB` unless necessary' (that may feel like a pedantic difference, but it isn't - it isn't LINQ's fault that the method was invoked, you passed `Concat` the **result** of the method call, so the method was called before LINQ was involved) - in which case the below answers should help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an approach like this to enumerate the collections one at a time:

The key bit is that `SmartConcat` takes `Func` rather than the **results** of the method call (that you are currently using). So it can stop executing as soon as it finds a match.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    static class ExtraLINQ
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> SmartConcat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params Func<IEnumerable<T>>[] extras)
        {
            foreach (var entry in source)
                yield return entry;


            foreach (var laterEntries in extras)
            {
                foreach (var laterEntry in laterEntries())
                {
                    yield return laterEntry;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Executes both functions
            var first = GetCollectionA().Concat(GetCollectionB()).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(first);

            // Executes only the first
            var otherFirst = GetCollectionA().SmartConcat(GetCollectionB).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(otherFirst);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> GetCollectionA()
        {
            var results = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            Console.WriteLine("GetBob");
            return results;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> GetCollectionB()
        {
            var results = new int[] { 4,5,6 };
            Console.WriteLine("GetBob4");
            return results;
        }

    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are dealing with a reference type, consider:

```
var result = GetCollectionA().FirstOrDefault() ?? GetCollectionB().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'd call it `UltraLazyConcat` :)

Comment: Haha, great idea Alexei!

Comment: Procedural error-prone code instead of "functional"? Looks good in the books

Comment: @fahadash was this comment "Procedural error-prone code instead of "functional"" related to some other comment? Not very clear what you suggesting here by itself.

Comment: `Procedural error-prone code instead of "functional"?` Huh? A number of LINQ operators are implemented in a manner not dissimilar to my answer here (in terms of loops and yield etc). I really struggle to see how your idea of `Enumerable.Range(1, 1).SelectMany(_ => GetCollectionB())` is more maintainable, less buggy or easier to understand than an explicit, simple, clear, working extension method.

Comment: @fahadash Also, did you ever say the solution couldn't involve loops (or whatever vague, unspecified concern you have with my solution? If so, please make that clear in your question. Also - my sincere appreciation for your **downvote of an answer that directly assists you**. What do you want from me? Blood?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my ugly looking hack works.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var seq = GetNumbers().Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 1).SelectMany(_ => GetNumbers())).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(seq);
    }

    static int[] GetNumbers()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetNumbers called");
        return new[]{1, 2, 3};
    }
}
```

`GetNumbers` was called only once

```
Hello World
GetNumbers called
1
```

Here is the fiddle 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/VDlL79

Comment: I appreciate this effort. It's helping me to do something where I only want the second sequence to contain data that hasn't been accessed as a side effect of executing the first sequence. It's helping me to iterate a large number of database items with a cursor and knock them out of the input query range, without materialising any of the sequences into memory, and still return a lazy IEnumerable to my calling logic.